# Can't find WCF Endpoint for service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I'm currently adding a WCF Service to my project, but I'm having trouble connecting to the service. I have two other services with similar configurations that work fine, and I can't find the reason why my new one is not connecting. When I try to connect to the endpoint, I get the following issue:

The type 'MyProject.MyServices.MyService, MyProject, Version=1.5.8.20715, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=PUBLICKEY', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

I've tried setting the Service attribute in my .svc to the other two implementations and those work fine.

myService.svc

```
<%@ServiceHost language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=PUBLICKEYTOKEN" 
    Service="MyProject.MyServices.MyService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
```

MyService.cs

```
    /// <inheritdoc />
    //[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Security", "CA2135", Justification = "Using Level 1 Security Rules as per Chuck's SP2016 Upgrade.")]
    //[SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, ObjectModel = true)]
    //[SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, ObjectModel = true)]
    [BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    [ServiceContract]
    public class MyService  : DataService<MyDataContext>
    {
        private SPWeb _web;

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MyService() : base()
        {

        }

        #endregion
        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Method for handling the incoming request
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments for the request</param>
        override protected void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
        {
        }

        [OperationContract]
        public string AddTwoNumbers()
        {
            return "I love WCF Services";
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I'm expecting an "Endpoint not found", but I am getting the serviceActivations error described above instead.

Comment: Your error message says for the type: `MyProject.MyServices.MyDataService` while both the code and svc seem to refer to a type `MyProject.MyServices.MyService` so somewhere else, not shown in the bits in your question you have a stale reference that you need to adjust. is there a web.config that has a serviceModel/services/service definition left unattended?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the actual project names for stack overflow. The project doesn't allow us to have a web config, but I've gotten closer to narrowing down the issue. MyDataContext extends DbContext, which I don't think WCF version 4 supports. When I try to upgrade versions, the sharepoint version I'm restricted to relies on version 4 so I'm not sure I'll be able to fix it. I've seen in other threads, that upgrading WCF Data Services to 5+ might fix it.

Comment: It is totally understandable you generalize names. Keep in mind that users who try to answer assume you present an [mcve] in your question. It prevent confusions like I had.

Comment: Good point, just edited the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is something wrong with the incorrect file/directory structure of your WCF web application, which caused this issue, could not find the right file.
For details, please refer to the below link.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4aab8a20-f39f-4c8d-aad2-8762ef87a66c/systemservicemodelservicehostingenvironmentserviceactivations-could-not-be-found?forum=wcf
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: I think the problem is MyDataContext extends DbContext from entity framework and it's having trouble interpreting the type. I can get it to work using a concrete class with IQueryables though (DataService<MyDbSetClass>). The solution should just be to upgrade WCF to a later version, but the sharepoint version I'm stuck with won't allow the upgrade so I'll have to find another solution.